# Несколько главных страниц на одном сайте?

Tags: wordpress, dns, веб-сайт

Коллеги, ситуация такая:

1. Есть несколько сайтов, каждый со своим доменным именем, со своей базой данных и своими страничками/шаблонами/медиа и прочим.. Все это в WP. У хостера один общий для всех аккаунт. Доменные имена привязаны к IP хостера и и все положенные DNS записи на NS серверах хостера. Все домены одного уровня, и не являются под-доменами друг друга
2. Начальник просит сделать так, чтобы все сайты слить в один сайт, но оставить доступ к главным страницам, связанным с каждым доменным именем. Например, пользователь пишет запрос в адресной строке броузера https://domain_name1, и попадает на страницу Homepage1, https://domain_name2, и попадает на страницу Homepage2 и так далее...

Помогите плиз разобраться, решаема ли задача в принципе? И как, если решаема... Моих знаний не хватает:(  Печенкой чую, что это из разряда "пойди туда, не знаю куда, принеси то, не знаю что.."

Comment: Что такое "слить"? И зачем, для чего?

Comment: "Слить" это в понятих босса иметь в итоге ОДИН сайт и Одну БД. И несколько разных доменнных имен ОДНОГО уровня, привязанных к этому сайту. Это понятно как делать. НО нужно как-то извратиться так, чтобы  оставить доступ к главным страницам, связанным с каждым доменным именем. Например, пользователь пишет запрос в адресной строке броузера https://domain_name1, и попадает на страницу Homepage1, https://domain_name2, и попадает на страницу Homepage2 и так далее..м, Для чего это - не знаю. босс внятно объяснить не может, но хочет:) В моих понятиях, это какое-то особо циничное извращение над DNS...

Comment: Один сайт=один домен (алиасы - это про другое). И главная может быть только одна. Так и скажи своему дурачку "боссу". А вот слить несколько сайтов в одну базу - можно. Но так будет делать только полный идиот. Кроме горы проблем никакого выигрыша не поимеет.

Comment: Не, ну это-то можно, и работает.. У меня на один сайт три домена смотрят и без проблем..  За коммент спасибо,! очень в тему :)

Comment: Правда, спасибо! Я так и знал, что сия задачка - изврат нереализуемый.. Хотя,, наверное, можно написать на php обработчик, который посмотрит, с каого аадресного запроса пришел пользователь и подсунет ему нужную страницу... Вопрос только зачем? Как вы правильно заметили, только гемморой!

Comment: У тебя алисы. Это легко сделать (хотя в случае с ВП это отдельные приключения на седалище). Алиасы на ФИЗИЧЕСКИ один набор файлов и данных из базы. Это СОВЕРШЕННО другое, нежели идиотские хотелки твоего босса.